# Angular - Check specific checkbox if ID/Value equals to value/property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web

I'm generating many checkboxes in my front-end

```html
<mat-checkbox *ngIf="isXXMode" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" class="xxCheckStyle" #xxCheck  color="primary" (change)="doFunction($event)" value="{{node.Id}}" id="{{node.Id}}">{{node.Id}}</mat-checkbox>
```

Node constructor:

```
export class xxxxxNode {
  constructor(
    public Id: string,
    public DisplayName: string,
    public Type: string,
    public isChecked = false
  ) { }
}
```

Each checkbox has it's own ID. When the page loads, i need to to change the value and check it if the id=specific value.
If X Cookie = 1, i want the checkbox with ID 1 to be checked. Someone out there can help me? i'm really struggling with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a isChecked property to the node object and set the ngModel value as node.isChecked

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let node of nodes">
  <mat-checkbox
    *ngIf="isXXMode"
    [(ngModel)]="node.isChecked"
    class="xxCheckStyle"
    #xxCheck
    color="primary"
    (change)="doFunction($event)"
    value="{{ node.Id }}"
    id="{{ node.Id }}"
    >{{ node.Id }}</mat-checkbox>
</ng-container>
```

**Component**

```js
specificValue = '3';

nodes = [
  new xxxxxNode('1', '11', 'check'),
  new xxxxxNode('2', '11', 'check'),
  new xxxxxNode('3', '11', 'check'),
  new xxxxxNode('4', '11', 'check'),
];

ngOnInit() {
  const selectedNode = this.nodes.find(
    (node) => node.Id === this.specificValue
  );
  if (selectedNode) {
    selectedNode.isChecked = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i wasn't able to make it work. I'll add the constructor of my nodes. I can't access the "isChecked" property

Comment: try to find the node and set the isChecked value to true in ngOnInit, I have updated the answer